# Protocols used to control Google Home and Amazon Echo speakers

Tags: amazon-echo, protocols, google-home, smart-assistants

Smart assistant products Google Home as well as Amazon Echo have companion apps to control the respective devices from smartphones.

What are the application level protocols that are used to control these assistants when:

- the smartphone is in same WiFi network as the smart assistant
- the smartphone is away and controls the assistant via cloud

Please do point to some publicly available documentation for these protocols.

Comment: They are using APIs over HTTPS